# How to use the Python string index in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, python, string, slice

In Python, you can do something like this:

```
string = "Hello World"
print(string[2:5])
# llo
```

What is the equivalent of that in JavaScript?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp

Comment: That syntax is called a [slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation), not an index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) function:

```
var str = "Hello world!"; 
var res = str.slice(2, 5); 
console.log(res) // llo
```

Comment: probably want to change the slice from 2 instead of 0.

Comment: @Gabip Apologies for editing the doc link but w3schools is not a good reference resource.

Answer (score 1):

You can use both `slice` or `substring`:

```js
const str = "Hello world!";

console.log(str.substring(2, 5));
console.log(str.slice(2, 5));
```

Comment: What is the difference between them two?

Comment: Minimal differences... 
with substring you can switch the start/end order and still works (If "start" is greater than "end", it will swap the two arguments).
With slice you can use negative number to start from the end.